# State is not updating after delete row in react-bootstrap-table.What the problem?

Tags: reactjs

**I am trying to delete a row and then load the state into localstorage.
But the state is not updated. There is no information on this in the documentation.
Google didn't help.**

**Options table**

```
const options = {
  page: 1,
  prePage: "⟵",
  nextPage: "⟶",
  firstPage: "⟸",
  lastPage: "⟹",
  afterInsertRow: this.onInsertRow,
  afterDeleteRow: this.onDeleteRow,
};

deleteRow={true}

onDeleteRow(){
 this.setState({ "items": JSON.stringify(this.state.items) })
}
```

**I noticed that when you delete the state, in principle, does not change. The element only disappears from the table.**

**Constructor has**

```
this.onDeleteRow= this.onDeleteRow.bind(this);
```

Comment: Your `onDeleteRow` just sets the items state value to a stringified version of itself. Where is the deleting supposed to be happening? I think you're missing relevant code

Comment: share your component.

Comment: When deleted in the manner described in the documentation, the element disappears completely from the application tree, but the state does not change in any way.

Comment: @b3hr4d which one?

Comment: I mean full component.

Comment: You should remove the item you deleted from your state manually, now you just set the same list to your state

Answer (score 0):

**
It was necessary to get the line number, and then filter the array in the state, thereby getting a new one.**

```
onDeleteRow(rowKeys) {
 for(let i = 0; i != rowKeys.length; i++){
  this.state.items = this.state.items.filter((item) => {return item.id !== 
  rowKeys[i]})
  }
 localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(this.state.items))
}
```